# XML Parsing with regards to Reverse Geocode

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, sax, reverse-geocoding

I am trying to reverse geocode my location using google maps to retrieve my current location's street name and perhaps postal code. I tried out many projects that used locality but i think my country always causes it to return a null(I am from Singapore).

Using XML, i am kinda unsure how am i suppose to parse the file i got from Google maps.

`serverAddress = new URL("http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=" + Double.toString(loc.getLatitude()) + "," + Double.toString(loc.getLongitude()) +
                        "&output=xml&oe=utf8&sensor=true&key=Hidden");`

Can anyone give me a direction here to move towards? Should i use the Document function to save and then proceed with SAX to parse the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
    String urlStr = "http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=" + lat + "," + lon + "&output=json&sensor=false";
  String response = "";
  List<Address> results = new ArrayList<Address>();
  HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

  Log.d("ReverseGeocode", urlStr);
  try {
         HttpResponse hr = client.execute(new HttpGet(urlStr));
         HttpEntity entity = hr.getEntity();

         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent()));

         String buff = null;
         while ((buff = br.readLine()) != null)
            response += buff;
          } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
       }
```

for more detail for ReverseGeocode see [this example](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/attachmentText?id=8816&aid=-9179841478848829245&name=ReverseGeocode.java&token=5b4fa0ac90429947339cf4740e3d66a3)

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll try this out. Sadly the link seems to be about JSON and I haven't tried stuff out till that far yet. Thanks for the help!